# mpeg dash on wowza server not working, status error 404 Not Found

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, wowza, mpeg-dash

adaptives links for mpeg dash on wowza server not working with me, the following are the steps that I used to publish video on wowza:

1. I install and configure Wowza server, and I tested it and it is working fine.
2. Transcode this [video](http://download.openbricks.org/sample/H264/h264_sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4) using **ffmepg** (I bring these command from [wowza documentation](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?192-Encoding-Suggestions-for-Video-on-Demand))
3. I test the files and all of them workig fine then I moved these files to wowza content folder and create the smil file as following:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil title="sintel">
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video width="320"  height="180" src="sintel_320p.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" >
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="200000" valuetype="data"></param>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="44100" valuetype="data"></param>
      </video>
      <video width="640"  height="360" src="sintel_640p.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" >
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="520000" valuetype="data"></param>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="44100" valuetype="data"></param>
      </video>
      <video width="320"  height="180" src="sintel_400p.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" >
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="270000" valuetype="data"></param>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="44100" valuetype="data"></param>
      </video>
      <video width="420"  height="270" src="sintel_700p.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" >
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="570000" valuetype="data"></param>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="44100" valuetype="data"></param>
      </video>
      <video width="720" height="406" src="sintel_1100p.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" >
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="1000000" valuetype="data"></param>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="44100" valuetype="data"></param>
      </video>
      <video width="1024" height="576" src="sintel_1300p.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" >
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="1200000" valuetype="data"></param>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="44100" valuetype="data"></param>
      </video>
      <video width="1080" height="608" src="sintel_1500p.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" >
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="1400000" valuetype="data"></param>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="44100" valuetype="data"></param>
      </video>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

4. I use the mpd file (http://191.237.26.137:1935/vod/smil:sintel.smil/manifest.mpd) with http://www.jwplayer.com/innovation/roadmap/mpeg-dash/

**Result: the video work for first few seconds the stop**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your description that there is keyframe alignment problem between the files. For switching to occur smoothly, each rendition must be key frame aligned meaning that a key frame that occurs at a specific timecode in one file must also occur at the same timecode in all of the other files. The default option with Dash is to request video segments are created and named based on the keyframe timecodes. If the player switches to a rendition that doesn't have a specific segment that is requested (because its key frame timing is off) then it will fail with a 404 response.

Wowza server builds the HTTP manifests dynamically from the moov atom data in the media files. In the case with an Adaptive bitrate manifest, it only reads the data from the first file and expects that the data will be identical in the other files. The default file plays fine because that was the one that the data came from and individual files play fine because fresh data is extracted from the file when each file is requested.

Id based segmentation (where the segments contain multiple key frames and are numbered sequentially, such as is used with HLS or HDS) is less susceptible to alignment problems however, you may notice the stream jumping forward or backwards if it switches to a different rendition and the timecodes in the new chunk don't align with the old chunk. Mpeg Dash can be configured to use ID based segmentation by changing the manifest url. See Delivery Formats for details.

Ffmpeg may do a better job at creating aligned encodings by disabling scene detection or doing two pass encoding and using the same first pass log for each second pass.